# Merge most of the black vertices of DAG together so that it remains DAG?

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

I have a DAG ( Directed Acyclic Graph ) with vertices having any of the 2 colours black or white. I need to merge as many black vertices together with the constraint that the graph should remain acyclic. Hence the final DAG should have minimum no. of black vertices. What is the best algorithm for this problem?

Comment: How is the merge operation defined? What happens to the edges? When can two black vertices be merged?

Comment: When 2 black vertices are merged, the edges of both the vertices are transferred to the final merged vertex. Any two black vertices can be merged, but the graph should remain acyclic.

Comment: y..z..lid...    what do you mean by "any two black vertices can be merged" ?? even if they are not adjacent ???

Comment: Yes they can be merged even if they are not adjacent, but it should not create cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible strategy. It reduces your problem to a colouring problem (which you can then use established heuristics algorithm from literature to solve).

Call the DAG G = (V,E) where V is the set of vertices. Let B be the set of black vertices and W be the set of white vertices. We want to construct a new simple graph G' = (B,E'). We construct it as follow:

```
algorithm contruct G' input: G
Let G' be a graph with vertex set B and no edges
for any pair of vertices v and v' where v,v' in B:
    Let (G'', v'') = merge (v,v',G)
    #comment: here, we let G'' to be the graph resulted from merging v and v'
    #also, let's assume that v and v' merge to become v''
    if detect_cycle(G'',v'') = true:
        add edge (v,v') into G'
output G'

algorithm detect_cycle(G,v):
do BFS in G starting at v, with the modification when reaching any vertex v':
    if v is connected to v': return true
return false
```

Note that G' is a simple graph and not a DAG and when doing BFS on G, you cannot go against the direction of an edge in G.
Essentially, we try to build G' with the set of black vertices in G such that if two vertices v adjacent to v' in G', then merging them causes cyclic graph in G. If v is not adjacent to v' in G' then it's safe to merge them. The problem then got reduced to find the minimum number of colors required to vertex-color G'. For background on vertex colouring, check out this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring. Basically vertex coloring is about finding the minimum number of sets where in each set, you can put in pairwise-nonadjacent vertices, then assign a label (or color) to each set (every vertex in the same set get the same label). Every black vertex with the same label in G' could be merged in G.

Heuristic algorithms for graph colouring could be found here:
http://heuristicswiki.wikispaces.com/Graph+coloring
and here: http://heuristicswiki.wikispaces.com/Degree+based+ordering

I hope it helps. Let me know if you find a better solution or a bug in the above solution.

Comment: Thanks @Tuan333 . This solution needs little modification. If two black vertices say v and v' in graph G are adjacent to each other and there is no other directed path between them, then we can merge these two vertices without creating a cycle. For ex. lets say the graph G is like v->v'->v'' and all these 3 vertices are black, then we can merge them into single vertex. But in above solution they will not be merged.

Comment: Errata: The statement "then there is a (directed) path in G (the DAG) leading from v to v'. If you merge v and v', then you will have an acyclic graph", I guess you meant cyclic graph?.

Comment: @quartz Ahhhh!!!!!  very nice point! Let's see if I could salvage the solution. Feel free to correct it (if you think it's salvageable).... very interesting. I will get back to you on this. The second comment is correct: it's a typo

Comment: @quartz I have adjusted the solution (and the comments below the algorithm). In the worst case senario, it'll have O(|B|^2|V|^2) complexity (O(|B|^2) pair of black vertices, and each BFS in the worst case gets O(|V|^2) complexity), which is not essentially very good. Maybe there are other more efficient methods. Thanks for the vote up though. Please post a more efficient method if you find one as I am also interested in this problem.

Comment: There is a corner case, where graph coloring may color graph in such a way that it produces cycle. For ex. consider the graph G =  b1->w1->b2  b3->w2->b4 . Above algorithm will produce G' = b1->b2 b3->b4. Now graph coloring may color {b1, b4 } = red and {b3, b2} = green. When we merge these vertices in original graph, it will create cycle.

Comment: I have added my answer in the answer section, please review it and give your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Let the graph be G = (V,E)

Topological sort the graph to get the list of vertices = L(V).
L(B) = list of black vertices extracted from L(V) with the order maintained.

Let n = no. of vertices in L(B).
Let DVA = empty array of deleted vertices of size n initialized with 0.

```
for i = vertices 1 to n in L(B)
   if(DVA[i] == 1)
     continue;
   for j = vertices i+1 to n in L(B)
     if(DVA[j] == 1)
        continue;
     if(detect_cycle(G, i, j) == 0) //merging i and j will not create cycle
        Merge j to i in G;
        DVA[j] = 1;
```

This algorithm works on the fact that topological order of black vertices do not change while merging 2 vertices (except for these 2 vertices) .
I guess this method will produce fairly good result, but I am not sure whether it will produce the optimal result of having least no. of black vertices.

Comment: uhh... it's a good one, no counter example comes to mind. Thanks for pointing out the bug on my solution- it's not a corner case, it's a solid bug! One question comes to mind though, the error from my algorithm seems to come from bad ordering of vertices while performing greedy coloring. If I order the vertices in G' as L(B) in yours (topological ordering), would our solutions be similar?

Comment: sorry for giving you an extra question btw, I would appreciate it if you give me some input on the problem!